# How to update value in input filed when click on add row in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: You can see in image value override and double show.]

You can see in image value override and double show. I need 1 input value show against 1 row when i click on PLUS button. value is update from ajax when i select vehicle number then value get from DB and show here Rate Field. Any one know about this solution.

```
$("select[name='vehicle_id[]']").change(function(){
      var vehicle = $(this).val();
      console.log(vehicle);
      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo url('admin/rate') ?>",
          method: 'POST',
          data: {vehicle:vehicle, _token:token},
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".inputContainer").each(function(){
                $(this).find('option').not(':first').remove();
            });
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                const $input = $('<input />')
                   .addClass('form-control rate')
                   .attr('name','rate[]')
                   .attr('id', 'rate'+i)
                   .attr('type', 'text')
                   .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
                   .val(item.rate)

                 // here we append it into container
                 $('.inputContainer').append($input);
            });
          }
      });
  });
```

Here is Table Code

```
<table  class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
                        <tr class="tr-header">
                            <th>Vehicle Number</th>
                            <th>Rate</th>
                            <th>Driver Name<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-modal-2">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                            </a> </th> 
                            <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                               <select name="vehicle_id[]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected>Select Vehicle</option>
                                @foreach($car_no as $car_no)
                                    <option value="{{$car_no->id}}">{{$car_no->car_number}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <!-- <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" value="" class="form-control rate" ></td> -->
                            <td><div class="inputContainer" ></td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="driver_id[]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" selected>Select Driver</option>
                                @foreach($driver_detail as $driver_detail)
                                    <option value="{{$driver_detail->id}}">{{$driver_detail->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is.

Comment: FYI, the quote formatting is for when you are actually quoting someone or something; please don’t misuse it just to make your own text “more colorful”.

Comment: Issue in picture. you can see there.

Comment: Well you are adding a new input field each time, so what did you expect? Easiest to solve, if you just restore what you have currently commented out - that there is an (empty) input field in that middle cell to begin with, and then you just set the value of that.

Comment: @misorude yes you are right but when i click to add 2nd row and get value from DB then Rate input value show double time.

Comment: Can you please provide example for you `data` variable from `success` callback?

Comment: That’s because you are not properly limiting your element selection to the current context. `$('.inputContainer')` selects _all_ elements with that class in the whole document, you need to limit it to the current table row of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify then `inputcontainer` element relative to current `TR` element. `.closest()` method can be used to traverse upto `TR` then use `.find()` to get the reference of `.inputcontainer` element

```
$("select[name='vehicle_id[]']").change(function(){
    //Target Parent TR
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    //Get Reference to inputContainer with in TR
    var inputcontainer = row.find(".inputContainer");

    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        //Modify existing container
        inputcontainer.find('input').remove();

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {            
            //Append
            inputcontainer.append($input);
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should close scope for your `.inputContainer` to current `<tr>`. And after that you should remove previously created `rate` input first and then create a new one.

```js
$("select[name='vehicle_id[]']").change(function() {
  var vehicle = $(this).val();
  const $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  $row.find(".inputContainer").each(function() {
    $(this).find('option').not(':first').remove();
  });

  $row.find(".inputContainer").find('.rate').remove();
  const $input = $('<input />', {
    class: 'form-control rate',
    name: 'rate[]',
    id: 'rate_id',
    type: 'text',
    readonly: 'readonly',
    value: 'VALUE FROM DB'
  });


  // here we append it into container
  $row.find('.inputContainer').append($input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
  <tr class="tr-header">
    <th>Vehicle Number</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Driver Name<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-modal-2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
      </a> </th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="vehicle_id[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Select Vehicle</option>
        <option value="les-808">LES-808</option>
        <option value="dsg-852">DSG-852</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inputContainer"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="driver_id[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Select Driver</option>
        @foreach($driver_detail as $driver_detail)
        <option value="{{$driver_detail->id}}">{{$driver_detail->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>

    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```